# Is counting maximal cliques in an incomparability graph #P-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, partial-order, clique

This question is motivated by a [MathOverflow question by Peng Zhang](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71994/what-is-the-number-of-maximal-antichain-in-a-poset/72033#72033).  Valiant showed that counting maximal cliques in a general graph is #P-complete, but what if we restrict to incomparability graphs (i.e., we want to count maximal antichains in a finite poset)?  This question seems natural enough that I suspect that it has been considered before, but I have not been able to locate it in the literature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this abstract](http://epubs.siam.org/sicomp/resource/1/smjcat/v12/i4/p777_s1?isAuthorized=no) for "The Complexity of Counting Cuts and of Computing the Probability that a Graph is Connected" (SIAM J. Comput. 12 (1983), pp. 777-788), counting anti-chains in a partial order is #P-complete. I don't have access to this paper so I can't tell if this result covers maximal anti-chains or not.

Comment: @András: I think that their result is about counting antichains (which are not necessarily maximal).  It might be easy to see that counting maximal antichains is also #P-complete, but I cannot see it.

Comment: @András: The question is about maximal antichains, not maximum-cardinality antichains.  I have not studied the reduction in the paper, so maybe their reduction also proves the #P-completeness of counting maximal antichains at the same time, but at least they are different problems.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: you are right, the Provan/Ball paper only shows that counting maximum-cardinality antichains is #P-hard.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Actually, if you look at the proof, you'll see that #P-completeness is proved for a class of posets in which all maximal antichains have the same cardinality. Namely, start with any bipartite graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and construct a bipartite graph $G'$ with $2n$ vertices by adding $n$ new vertices $\{v' : v\in V\}$ and $n$ new edges $\{(v,v'): v\in V\}$.  Then, if $V_1$ and $V_2$ is a bipartition of the vertex set of $G'$, define a poset on $V_1\cup V_2$ by setting $x<y$ if $x\in V_1$ and $y\in V_2$ and $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in $G'$. So this does answer my question.