# Does faster exact algorithm for counting independent sets in comparability graphs than general graph exisits?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, counting-complexity

Sorry for not-precise question. :-(

There are several papers concerning exact counting (maximum) independent sets in general graphs. Actually, they concerns counting of solutions of 2SAT. The best of them is $O(1.23^n)$. But the algorithms do not use the specific information of comparability graphs.

So I wonder whether there exists more powerful(faster) exact algorithm for counting independent sets in comparability graphs?

Comment: Please state your question precisely, but that sounds like a duplicate of [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7637/is-counting-maximal-cliques-in-an-incomparability-graph-p-complete).

Answer (score 5):

Bipartite graphs are comparability graphs, and it's known (since Provan and Ball) that counting the number of independent sets in bipartite graphs is #P-complete.

J. S. Provan and M. O. Ball. The complexity of Counting Cuts and of Computing the Probability that a Graph is Connected.  SIAM J. Comput. 12 (1983) 777-788.

If I haven't mistaken, this should answer your question.

Comment: I'm afraid this wasn't an intended answer.  Probably, I need a clarification on what the "reduction" in the question exactly means.

Comment: I am sorry, I have just edited my question. the older one is not preise.