# Number of subsets on a set with partial order

Tags: ds.algorithms, counting-complexity, partial-order

Given a set $S$ with strict partial order $<$. Let $A\subseteq S$ be a downward-closed subset of $S$ (in other words, if $a<b$ and $b\in A$, then $a\in A$). How many subsets of $S$ are downward-closed?

Are there algorithms that can solve the problem in time polynomial in $|S|$?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using $<$ instead of $\leq$?

Comment: strict order make sure the graph is for the order is a DAG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See three closely related questions [Does faster exact algorithm for counting independent sets in comparability graphs than general graph exisits?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7679/does-faster-exact-algorithm-for-counting-independent-sets-in-comparability-graph) and [Is counting maximal cliques in an incomparability graph #P-complete?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7637/is-counting-maximal-cliques-in-an-incomparability-graph-p-complete) and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49515/on-the-number-of-antichains-of-a-poset

They are all on antichains rather than downward-closed sets but downward-closed sets correspond one-for-one with the antichains of their maximal elements.

I believe both of the cstheory questions have answers with references that also answer your question: no, the problem is #P-complete.

Answer (score 6):

An additional comment: in case your partially ordered set is the power set of a given set (e.g., [n]) ordered by the inclusion, more is known when n is small. Specifically see the [Dedekind numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) article and the [Sloane integer sequence](http://oeis.org/A000372). The asymptotic behavior has been studied also. Hansel in 1966 proved that the number of antichains of subsets of an n-set is upper-bounded by $3^{{n \choose \lfloor n/2\rfloor}}$. Later, Kleitman and Markowsky improved this bound. For further results see the references in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number). Finally, another reference (in addition to the Provan-Ball paper which appears in one of the links above) of interest to you probably is ["On the relative complexity of approximate counting problems"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=on%20the%20relative%20complexity%20of%20approximate%20counting%20problems&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.88.5821%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=OB22TqywLYXq0gGEwdzSBw&usg=AFQjCNF1OpHwdY0jm_jQtsnwAU7DzfVsFQ&sig2=IJaqI2GexuH0xijrV8ROcQ), by Dyer, Goldberg, Greenhill and Jerrum.